# Get href value from anchor tag with bash

Tags: html, regex, bash

This is the html I'm parsing

```
<li id="dl_linux_32">
   <a href="link">Link</a>
</li>
<li id="dl_linux_64">
   <a href="another_link">Another Link</a>
</li>
```

with this `curl URL 2>&1 | grep -oE 'href="([^"#]+)"' | sed "s/ /%20/g" | cut -f2 -d "="` I'm able to get all `href`'s values. However I just want the `href`'s value of the anchor  inside the `li` with `id` equals to `dl_linux_32`.

Can someone help me finish the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex I was looking for is `dl_linux_32.+href="([^"#]+)"`. I'm searching for all `href`'s values that before it has one or more characters and `dl_linux_32`

Comment: How could you implement this regex?

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 1):

**Perl One-Liner**

The regex must check across multiple lines. In this sort of situation, a Perl one-liner will work beautifully.

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print "$&\n" if /<li id="dl_linux_32">\s*<a \Khref="[^"]+"/' yourfile
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm only supposed to use bash. However your solution looks beautiful

Comment: Hahaha Wish I could :P

Comment: @hwnd You mean, as a Perl one-liner, you could shorten it?

Comment: @hwnd You're right, moving the print upfront makes it shorter. Nice idea using a capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Through GNU awk,

```
$ awk -F'"' -v RS="</li>" '/<li\s*id=\"dl_linux_32\">/{print $4}' file
link
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the html is valid XML, you can use a tool that incorporates xpath searching

```
echo '<html>
      <li id="dl_linux_32">
         <a href="link">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li id="dl_linux_64">
         <a href="another_link">Another Link</a>
      </li>
      </html>
' | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//li[@id="dl_linux_32"]/a/@href'
```

```
link
```